# Tic Tac Toe Score

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

This is the code that I currently have for tic tac toe and it works well and I fixed how to keep score, however, I feel like the code is not nice and clean. Is there any way to make the code cleaner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;


      public class TicTacToe{
          public static int a;
          public static int b; 
          public static int c;
          public static int d;
          public static int e;
          public static int f;
          public static int g;
          public static int h;
          public static int i;
                    public static boolean Winner(){
                          if(a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1){
                                     return true;       
                                    } 
                              else if(d == 1 && e == 1 && f == 1){
                                     return true;       
                                    } 
                              else if(g == 1 && h == 1 && i == 1){
                                     return true;      
                                    } 
                              else if(a == 1 && d == 1 && g == 1){
                                     return true;      
                                    } 
                              else if(b == 1 && e == 1 && h == 1){
                                     return true;       
                                    } 
                              else if(c == 1 && f == 1 && i == 1){
                                     return true;      
                                    } 
                              else if(a == 1 && e == 1 && i == 1){
                                     return true;      
                                    } 
                              else if(c == 1 && e == 1 && g == 1){
                                     return true;       
                                    } 
                              else if(a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 2){
                                     return true;       
                                    }
                              else if(d == 2 && e == 2 && f == 2){
                                     return true;      
                                    }
                              else if(g == 2 && h == 2 && i == 2){
                                     return true;
                                    }       
                              else if(a == 2 && d == 2 && g == 2){
                                     return true;   
                                    }    
                              else if(b == 2 && e == 2 && h == 2){
                                     return true; 
                                    }      
                              else if(c == 2 && f == 2 && i == 2){
                                     return true; 
                                    }      
                              else if(a == 2 && e == 2 && i == 2){
                                     return true;    
                                    }  
                              else if(c == 2 && e == 2 && g == 2){
                                     return true;
                                    }       
                                     return false;
                                    }
                public static void main (String args[]){
                        String line1 = "1 | 2 | 3";
                        String line2 = "-------";
                        String line3 = "4 | 5 | 6";
                        String line4 = "-------";
                        String line5 = "7 | 8 | 9";
                        String line6 = "-------";
                               Scanner tic = new Scanner (System.in);
                               Scanner tac =  new Scanner (System.in);

                                    System.out.println("Welcome to a game of Tic Tac Toe");
                                    System.out.println("The game for those who aren't good at anything else.");
                                    System.out.println (line1);
                                    System.out.println (line2);
                                    System.out.println (line3);
                                    System.out.println (line4);
                                    System.out.println (line5);
                                    System.out.println (line6);


                    for (int i=0; i < 7; i++)
                       {

                        System.out.println("First player please choose a number. ");
                        int number = tic.nextInt();

                        if (number == 1){
                        line1 = line1.replace ("1","O");
                        a = 1;
                        }
                        if (number == 2){
                        line1 = line1.replace ("2","O");
                        b = 1;
                        }
                        if (number  == 3){
                        line1 = line1.replace ("3","O");
                        c = 1;
                        }
                        if (number == 4){
                        line3 = line3.replace ("4","O");
                        d = 1;
                        }
                        if (number == 5){
                        line3 = line3.replace ("5","O");
                        e = 1;
                        }
                        if (number == 6){
                        line3 = line3.replace ("6","O");
                        f = 1;
                        }
                        if (number == 7){
                        line5 = line5.replace ("7","O");
                        g = 1;
                        }
                        if (number == 8){
                        line5 = line5.replace ("8","O");
                        h = 1;
                        }
                        if (number == 9){
                        line5 = line5.replace ("9","O");
                        i = 1;
                        }


                            System.out.println(line1);
                            System.out.println(line2);
                            System.out.println(line3);
                            System.out.println(line4);
                            System.out.println(line5);
                                  if(Winner()){
                                  System.out.println("First Player wins.");
                                  System.exit(1);
                                      }
                            if(a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && d != 0 && e != 0 && f != 0 && g != 0 && h != 0 && i != 0){
                                  System.exit(1);
                                      }
                        System.out.println("Second player please choose a number. ");
                        int number2 = tac.nextInt();

                        if (number2 == 1){
                        line1 = line1.replace ("1","X");
                        a = 2;
                         }
                        if (number2 == 2){
                        line1 = line1.replace ("2","X");
                        b = 2;
                         }
                        if (number2  == 3){
                        line1 = line1.replace ("3","X");
                        c = 2;
                         }
                        if (number2 == 4){
                        line3 = line3.replace ("4","X");
                        d = 2;
                         }
                        if (number2 == 5){
                        line3 = line3.replace ("5","X");
                        e = 2;
                         }
                        if (number2 == 6){
                        line3 = line3.replace ("6","X");
                        f = 2;
                         }
                        if (number2 == 7){
                        line5 = line5.replace ("7","X");
                        g = 2;
                         }
                        if (number2 == 8){
                        line5 = line5.replace ("8","X");
                        h = 2;
                         }
                        if (number2 == 9){
                        line5 = line5.replace ("9","X");
                        i = 2;
                         }
                              System.out.println(line1);
                              System.out.println(line2);
                              System.out.println(line3);
                              System.out.println(line4);
                              System.out.println(line5);
                              System.out.println(line6);
                                 if(Winner()){
                                    System.out.println("Second Player wins.");
                                    System.exit(1);
                                       }
                             if(a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && d != 0 && e != 0 && f != 0 && g != 0 && h != 0 && i != 0){
                                    System.exit(1);
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

This works but is there a more efficient way of fixing it?

Comment: What do you mean "it just doesn't seem to work"? I don't see any variable meant to keep track of scores.

Comment: Shouldn't you first implement an algorithm to detect a winner? That's currently missing. And you should do a bit research about avoiding code duplication. Even if you're new you should care about that.

Comment: Code formatting is horrendous. Please format (indent code) for human readability. --- Too much repeated code. Have you learned about *methods* yet? --- Please read: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Btw, if your code is finished, everything is done and works fine, then please share your code here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ so others can give you hints in improving the code structure. You may learn something from them.

Comment: @Tom please [read this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @PatrickParker You said you think it is a bad idea to post the complete code on CR, so can you tell us why? Which of the on-topic rules of CR do you see violated?

Comment: @Tom this is not the place for that discussion. try asking a mod in the chat.

Comment: @PatrickParker Ah ok, you have no argument, I understand it :).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I forgot to add it when I posted the code. It was a bit frustrating. I'm editing it now.

Comment: @Tom No, need to be rude. I do know what a method is but keeping score was my main issue.

Comment: @Andreas No, need to be rude. I do know what a method is but keeping score was my main issue. I will format it right now.

Comment: @OziIlo I wasn't being rude. I was trying to determine your skill level. It was also a *hint* for how to do it better. If you know about methods, you should change your `line1` to `line6` local variables to be fields, and create a method for printing them, then call that method instead of repeating the 6 `println` statements over and over and over and over and again. Code will be much leaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the winner and loser of the game, and giving proper score you have to check the state of your game board. parsing the text is a bit complicated, and requires a lot of unneccesary work, so I suggest you somehow represent the board in a `matrix`.

**Example:**

```
char[][] gameBoard = new char[3][3];
```

This way, when you recieve an input through the scanner, as your code does, you will enter the char you want ('O' or 'X') to the gameBoard variable like this:

```
// number is 1-9 according to your code
int row = number/3; // Gives you 0 or 1 or 2
int col = number%3; // Gives you 0 or 1 or 2
gameBoard[row][col] = 'O'; // or 'X'
```

After each turn of each player, you will call the following function (complete the code yourself, look up **java matrix iteration**):

```
public boolean hasWinner(int playerNumber)
{
    // playerNumber will be passed according to which player did the current turn.
    // The function will try to search for the sequence that wins the game.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't seem to detect when a player wins.
Once you have implemented that, all you have to do is track the score of each player in integers. And when you detect that either player has won, increment the integer corresponding to his score. :)

Comment: Also,  the game never ends, even after all the squares are filled with Xs and Os.

Comment: @DavidChoweller No, it ends, but the `for` loop counter is too high (no 420 pun intended :P).

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToe
{
private String [] line = new String[5];
private Scanner input;
private int counter;

public TicTacToe()
{
    counter = 0;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    line[0] = "1 | 2 | 3";
    line[1] = "_______";
    line[2] = "4 | 5 | 6";
    line[3] = "_______";
    line[4] = "7 | 8 | 9";
}

public void rulesOfTheGame(){
    System.out.println("Tic Tac Toe");
    System.out.println(line);
}

public void replace(String str)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Player choose a number.");
        int number; 
        number = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            number = input.nextInt();
            if ((number == i) && ((i == 1) || (i == 2) || (i == 3))){
                String num = "" + i + "";
                line[0] = line[0].replace(num,str);
                counter++;
            }
            if ((number == i) && ((i == 4) || (i == 5) || (i == 6))){
                String num = "" + i + "";
                line[2] = line[2].replace(num,str);
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                String num = "" + i + "";
                line[4] = line[4].replace(num,str);
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}

public void winnerWinnerChickenDinner()
{
    if ((counter >= 5) && (counter < 9)){
        String isItOver = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Getting down to the wire here, is the game over yet! CAPITAL Y FOR YES OR CAPITAL N FOR NO", "Game Over");
        if (isItOver.equals("Y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Game Over");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("");
        }
    }
    else if (counter == 9){
        System.out.println("Game Over");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

This is the most efficient code. I could actually create. I am sure that there is even easier way to do this; however, I think that this is still very concise with almost no repeated code.

Comment: Also, you would need to make a new client class to actual get a print value going.